# Defining a single array with indexes of 'a'..'z' and '0'..'9' in Pascal

Tags: pascal

I am learning the language right now so I am really not strong when it comes to the syntax and I wasn't able to find an answer online.

I could split the array to two array easily, but when I tried to define something like:

```
Counts: Array['a'..'z','0'..'9'] of Integer;
```

I get this error which I am not able to solve:

```
Incompatible types: got "ShortInt" expected "Array[48..57] Of SmallInt
```

Is defining an array like this possible? Thanks.

Comment: Your declaration means `Array[97..122] of Array[48..57] of Integer`. Use it as: `Counts['a','0'] := 42;` If your intention was to create a one-dimensional array with a gap for indexes, it is not possible.

Comment: That line compiles fine here. Are you sure your error is in that line?

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort, `Counts['a'] := 42;`  will give `E2010 Incompatible types: 'array[48..57] of Integer' and 'Integer'` in Delphi. I guess a similar error is what the OP is seeing.

Comment: Which Pascal compiler are you using?

Comment: @MartynA the one over here: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_pascal_compiler

Comment: These online compilers seem a bit quirky judging by the qs which involve them.  Unless you absolutely *have* to use that one, download the version of Lazarus (an IDE similar to Delphi) that suits you from here https://www.lazarus-ide.org/index.php?page=downloadsi  It includes the best freeware Pascal implementaion by far, FreePascal (aka FPC).  Btw, your array declaration compiles fine in FPC.

Comment: Btw, you are aware that your Counts array is a two-dimensional array, so assignments should be like `Counts['d', '4'] := 66;` ?

Answer (score 1):

The declaration

```
Counts: Array['a'..'z','0'..'9'] of Integer;
```

means `Array[97..122] of Array[48..57] of Integer`.  It is a 2-dimensional array.

Use it as:

```
Counts['a','0'] := 42;
```

If your intention was to create a one-dimensional array with a gap for indexes, it is not possible.

---

The error seen from the [compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_pascal_compiler) is because the array is accessed like it was a one-dimensional array, likely something like this:

```
program Hello;
var
  Counts: Array['a'..'z','0'..'9'] of Integer;
begin
  Counts['a'] := 42;//Error: Incompatible types: got "ShortInt" expected "Array[48..57] Of SmallInt"
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried declaring the two dimensional array as a type and then assigning it to a variable:

```
Type
  twoD = Array['a'..'z','0'..'9'] of Integer;
Var
  V2: twoD
```